Error while installing the dart and flutter boilerplate to enable gRPC
I have been following the guide here to integrate my flutter app with a web scraping python script.
On running the following command:
./starter-kit/prepare-sources.sh \
--proto ./service.proto \
--flutterDir ./flutter_application_1 \
--pythonDir ./server

I have run into the following error

Building wheels for collected packages: tinyaes
  Building wheel for tinyaes (pyproject.toml): started
  Building wheel for tinyaes (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  Building wheel for tinyaes (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1

I have already tried pip install wheel.
Requirement already satisfied: wheel in c:\users\aksha\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (0.43.0)

Any help would be appreciated~!
I expected the command to run successfully but ran into the error.
Edit 10/4/2024:
I have checked my system for Microsoft Visual C++ 14.38.33135.0 but:
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
[end of output]

To try and resolve this I've downloaded Visual Studio Build Tools from here
However, It still gives the same error message.
Edit 19/8/2024:
Ok the problem got solved but I'm not sure why downloading the tools directly without the use of visual studio did not work. I was working on a completely different project where I had to use visual studio and installed the build tools from inside the software. This has solved my problem so ('<').

Try to pip install tinyaes. Wheel is not a package to install but a state of a package that can be installed. Said differently: when you install a package, you are installing a wheel (most of the time).

@j-i-l
I tried to install tinyaes, it gives the same error message.
